# RadioButton behaving in unpredictable way

Tags: android, android-button

I have two `RadioGroup`s that have to be related to each other. When I check a button on the first group, I need the corresponding button on the other group to be disabled and, if it was checked, to be unchecked too.

I tried to achieve this by using, when a button from the first group is clicked,  `RadioButton.setEnabled(false)` on the corresponding button and `RadioButton.setChecked(false)` if it was also checked.

But after these operations, when I use `RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()`, it doesn't return `-1` as expected ([here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId%28%29)) but it still returns the ID of the button I unchecked and disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using `RadioGroup.clearCheck()` instead of manually unchecking the button I wanted to, but still I'd like to know why does Android behave like this.
I mean, why there's a method called `setChecked()` if it doesn't seem to work the way it should, at least when passing a `false` parameter to it?

Comment: Its hard to say without seeing exactly how/where you are doing it. This should work the way I understand what you are doing as long as you understand that `setEnabled(false)` disables the button and doesn't change the `checked` parameter.

Comment: I know `setEnabled(false)` doesn't uncheck the button, and that's why I call `setChecked(false)`, which should uncheck it.

Comment: Ok, I thought you probably knew that but that was the only thing I, or probably anyone, could offer without out seeing how you are doing it. There may be something little you are missing as far as how you are calling it or where